# Saving black and white image in the database

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing, binary

I need to save black and white images in a database. They are just sequences of bits - either white or black. What is the most efficient way to store them in the database?

My idea is to save their dimensions and then just put them as binary code that could be then resolved as 1011000111 etc. Those images can be quite big. Saving them as image files doesn't make sense, because I'll need to access their pixel data on regular basis and I don't want to put any color information. I said black and white, but it can be yellow and pink too.

What column type should I use and how can I encode and then decode my images?

Comment: See blob data type for storing data like this.

Comment: u need to get at the individual pixel matrix ? And is pink 0, or 1 :>

Comment: There is an upvote on the blob comment, was this enough feedback?  This question has been abandoned.  Have you solved it Robo?  Do you have an comprehensive answer for all of the subquestions to submit?

Comment: @mickmackusa This question is 2 years ago, I don't quite remember to be honest. I think BLOB answer was NOT enough, because I knew BLOB at the time of writing it.